# Searching for links into HTML to use InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using `$http.get();` to get the HTML content of my post. But, some posts has links and when I click in these links at the App they don't open.
So, I need help to find a way to search for links (`<a>`) into the HTML and make this opens in System Browser using InAppBrowser.
Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried my comment below ?

Comment: I will try and comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas,

Last time I also used InAppBrowser with the following code.

```
<div onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com.sg/', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;"></div>
```

So if you want to plug it into your application, let do so. I supposed you store a data result from $http.get() into $scope.respondData variable. And each object have a field to store link named linkToWebSite

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in respondData" ng-if="item.linkToWebSite"> //display if linkToWebSite not empty.
        <a onclick="window.open('{item.linkToWebSite}', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```